# c++ socket read() return -1 while connecting to server some times

Tags: c++, sockets

I am new to c++ , and i am working on socket programming while sending data from server to client the read() function returns -1 during sometime and in sometime it returns 64 and working fine. I have attached my code below and please give  a better solution to me.

server.cpp

```
  if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
{
    logger("socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
                                              &opt, sizeof(opt)))
{
    logger("setsockopt");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.4");
address.sin_port = htons( PORT );


// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                             sizeof(address))<0)
{
    logger("bind failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
{
    logger("listen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

 while (true)
 {
                    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
                    {
                            logger("socket not accept");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    //valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
                    //printf("%s\n",buffer );
                    send(new_socket , hash_key , strlen(hash_key) , 0 );
                    //printf("Hello message sent\n");
   }
return 0;
```

client.cpp

```
                 arg |= O_NONBLOCK;
                  if( fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, arg) < 0) {
                     fprintf(stderr, "Error fcntl(..., F_SETFL) (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
                     exit(0);
                  }
                   int res;
                   res = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
                  if (res < 0) {
                     if (errno == EINPROGRESS) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "EINPROGRESS in connect() - selecting\n");
                        do {
                           tv.tv_sec = 50;
                           tv.tv_usec = 0;
                           FD_ZERO(&myset);
                           FD_SET(sock, &myset);
                           res = select(sock+1, NULL, &myset, NULL, &tv);
                           if (res < 0 && errno != EINTR) {
                              fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                              exit(0);
                           }
                           else if (res > 0) {
                              // Socket selected for write
                              lon = sizeof(int);
                              if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*)(&valopt), &lon) < 0) {
                                 fprintf(stderr, "Error in getsockopt() %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                                 exit(0);
                              }
                              // Check the value returned...
                              if (valopt) {
                                 fprintf(stderr, "Error in delayed connection() %d - %s\n", valopt, strerror(valopt)
                );
                                 exit(0);
                              }
                              break;
                           }
                           else {
                              fprintf(stderr, "Timeout in select() - Cancelling!\n");
                              exit(0);
                           }
                        } while (1);
                     }
                     else {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                        exit(0);
                     }
                     valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);
                    cout<<valread<<endl;
```

Comment: See `man 2 read`. What `errno` set to? You should do `if (valread == -1) perror("read");` to print out what the actual error occurred.

Comment: You may have a look at https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/SmlParser. In this program I implemented the Acceptor/Connector  Reactor/Proactor/ACT pattern. Problem could be that you can accept a lot of connections. You need to handle the returned fd correctly. Store in a vector or somehere. Sorry to say, but not so easy . . .

Answer (score 0):

You listen incoming connection from clients and send data to client in same loop in server side.
You should seperate them using thread.Your server code blocking on accept routine.

Comment: Please avoid telling people they should break their minimal example code into multiple threads. That overly complicates the issue presented and is not always a good design path. Here the issue is in the use of `connect` which can fail for a number of reasons other than `EINPROGRESS` that are unhandled by the code or in handling the return from `read`.